# USART communication problem on PIC18F6722

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c

I am trying to use enable USART communication on a PIC18F6722 microcontroller.  More specifically enable the receiver and attach a receive interrupt to it.

The datasheet describes the relevant bits as such

```
RC2IE: USART2 Receive Interrupt Enable bit
1 = Enables the USART2 receive interrupt
0 = Disables the USART2 receive interrupt

CREN: Continuous Receive Enable bit Asynchronous mode:
1 = Enables receiver
0 = Disables receiver
```

For some reason this piece of code doesn't do it though:

```
PIE3bits.RC2IE = 1; 
RCSTA2bits.CREN = 0;
```

I want to set both of these to 1 although it isn't working.  Any ideas?

[I previously asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630451/initializes-the-uart-with-high-priority-receive-interrupt-in-pic18lf6722) although I didn't get any useful information

Comment: It'd be worth posting some more complete code that includes your interrupt handler and other USART init code.

Comment: @PeterJ I already post my question thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you posting again when your linked question already has answers?

Comment: @ShannonStrutz i didn't get any useful information

Comment: @user3732308 okay well I have edited the question to make it much more reader friendly.

Comment: @user3732308  Please don't cross-post.  [StackExchange policy is against cross-posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).  You can make a flag to the moderators and they will migrate the question to a different stack.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable global interrupts (GIE) and peripheral interrupts (PEIE). Check out register 10-1 (INTCON) and figure 10-1 in the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39646b.pdf). Without them, your interrupt will never happen.

[image]